# How to update all List<> items with loop, and then keep using the updated list

Tags: c#, list

C#:
I create a List from EF query output > .ToList()
I then update a field value for all items; tried both using foreach or using for(i= ...)

Here:

```
for (int p = 0; p < points_list.Count; p++)
                {
                    var ppp = points_list[p];
                    ppp.pp.X_ID = labels[p];
                    points_list[p]= ppp;
                }
```

I then access "points_list" in the same context that field remains null and my code fails ...

How can I update the list and keep using locally?

Comment: Of what type is your list exactly? Is the element type a class or struct? (This makes the whole difference!)

Comment: Debug the code to see if `labels[p] == null`. Also, you can assign the value in one line, like this: `points_list[p].pp.X_ID = labels[p];`

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.ToList().ForEach(c => c.PropertyToSet = value);
```

Use collection.ToList().ForEach(c => { c.Property1ToSet = value1; c.Property2ToSet = value2; });

Comment: `ForEach` is an extension that is not in the standard framework libraries.

Comment: This is what I did (tried both foreach and for, including generating a new object. Did not work. The property of the original list is not updated.